# Border for radio button

Tags: html, css, radio-button

I have the code like this, which I can't modify handly (only with css)

```
<label class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="showTabs" checked="" value="1"> LABEL 1
</label>

<label class="radio">
   <input type="radio" name="showTabs" value="2"> LABEL 2
</label>
```

How can I add border around for checked radiobutton + label?

Comment: Can you use JavaScript?

Comment: no. just for that feature I don't wanna do this

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code, hope this is what you expecting

```css
.radio{
   position:relative;
   display:inline-block;
}

.ch-style{
  display:block;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  bottom:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  z-index: 0;
}


input[type="radio"]:checked ~ .ch-style{ 
   border:1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<label class="radio">
<input type="radio" name="showTabs" value="2"> LABEL 2
<span class="ch-style"><span>
</label>
```

Comment: again modified html code. Ok, I'm understand, it's impossible